# Python: Does any() stop iterating through list/generator once truthy value is found?

Tags: python, performance, any

If you have:

```
if any(word in sentence for sentence in sentences):
```

and `sentences` is a long list of say, 10,000 sentence-length strings, will `any()` iterate through the entire list to determine if any are true, or will it stop looking once a true value is found, since the `any()` value is already determined to be true?

If it's truly iterating through the entire list regardless, then of course if would be faster to use a for loop and break once found, as opposed to using `any()`, that's why I'm asking.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it does short-circuit like that. From [the documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#any):

> Equivalent to:
>
> ```
> def any(iterable):
>     for element in iterable:
>         if element:
>             return True
>     return False
> ```

One easy way to confirm is with a large or infinite iterable:

```
>>> any(True for i in range(1_000_000_000_000))
True
```

(instant)

Comment: Thanks! And now that I understand this is called "short-circuiting", its easy to find more information on the subject. Did not know there was a name for this.